# Java: How to let 2 Thread alternating use a method

Tags: java, multithreading

kinda new to Threads.

I have 2 Threads and want them to alternately use a method. So Thread 1 does the method, then waits. Then Thread 2 wakes Thread 1 and does the method. Then Thread 1 wakes Thread 2 and does the method etc.
But somehow I got a deadlock and I don't understand why.

```
public class NewT extends Thread{


public void print(NewT x)
{

    synchronized(this)
    {

        System.out.println("x"+x);
        notifyAll();
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public void run()
{

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        print(this);                
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    NewT one = new NewT();
    NewT two = new NewT();


    one.start();
    two.start();




}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the `synchronized` is on `this` each thread is locking its own object, and there is actually no synchronization; and they are waiting an event that will never come.

UPDATE:

As someone noted, using a common `lock` object is not enough because both threads will end up waiting.

Here is a solution:

```
private static Object lock = new Object();
private static NewT previous;

public static void print(NewT x) throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized(lock) {
        while (previous == x) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("x"+ x);
        previous = x;
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well ... This is one problem in the above code. By solving that, you still have a program that never ends. There is a second problem with the order of the `notifyAll` and `wait` calls.

Answer (score 0):

`Wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` works fine when you are sharing on common/shared objects. In your case, you are notifying on yourself (same thread instance) and waiting for indefinite time. As a result JVM not able to print after 2 entries.

Sample Code:

```
package ThreadsTricks;

/**
 *
 * @author pcu
 */

public class PrintOddEven {

boolean odd;
int count = 1;
int MAX = 20;

public void printOdd() {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (count < MAX) {
            System.out.println("Checking odd loop");

            while (!odd) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Odd waiting : " + count);
                    wait();
                    System.out.println("Notified odd :" + count);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Odd Thread :" + count);
            count++;
            odd = false;
            notify();
        }
    }
}

public void printEven() {

    try {
      //  Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        while (count < MAX) {
            System.out.println("Checking even loop");

            while (odd) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Even waiting: " + count);
                    wait();
                    System.out.println("Notified even:" + count);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Even thread :" + count);
            count++;
            odd = true;
            notify();

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PrintOddEven oddEven= new PrintOddEven();
    oddEven.odd = true;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            oddEven.printEven();

        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            oddEven.printOdd();

        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

this is my first answer, please let me know if there are any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see with your code is that you do not have a shared object to lock on and one of your threads will wait forever (as the other thread has completed its activity and move on...). I personally do not believe there is a deadlock here.

This should help, however I would recommend using `java.util.concurrent` package for better alternatives. I personally do not recommend working with `wait` and `notify` / `notfiyAll`

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class AlternatingThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object lock = new Object();
        NewT one = new NewT(lock);
        NewT two = new NewT(lock);

        one.start();
        two.start();
    }

    public static class NewT extends Thread {
        private Object lock;

        public NewT(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        public void print(NewT x) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                System.out.println(Instant.now().getNano() + "ns x-" + x);
                lock.notifyAll();

                try {
                    // timeout depends on how long you need for the activity to complete.
                    lock.wait(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                print(this);
            }
            System.out.println(Instant.now().getNano() + "ns Final-" + this);
        }
    }
}
```

This produces following output

```
573000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
576000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
577000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
577000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
577000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
577000000ns x-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
577000000ns x-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]
577000000ns Final-Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
677000000ns Final-Thread[Thread-2,5,main]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

> Note: without timeout of 100ms Thread-2 would be waiting forever.